# LARAVEL 8: Class 'Database\Seeders\DB' not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working with seeder to fill my `users` table, so I created a new seeder called `UserSeeder` and then I added these codes to it:

```
public function run()
{
    foreach(range(1,10) as $item)
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => "name $item",
            'email' => "email $item",
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => "password $item" 
        ]);
    }
}
```

After that I tried `php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder` but it shows me:

> Error
>
> **Class 'Database\Seeders\DB' not found**

which is related to this line:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
```

So why it is not found there, what should I do now?

Comment: namespacing, you would have to import/alias the `DB` class to use it in that file like that

Comment: @lagbox Would you please tell me where is it and what should I write?

Comment: `use DB;` after the  namespace declaration

Comment: I had this problem too and I solved this issue by running `composer dump-autoload` after creating a new seeder class or changing its namespace.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's because Laravel will look for DB class in the current namespace which is Database\Seeders.

Since Laravel has facades defined in `config/app.php` which allows you to use those classes without full class name.

```
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
```

You can either declare DB class after the namespace declaration with

```
use DB;
```

or just use it with backslash.

```
    \DB::table('users')->insert([
```

Comment: The declaration approach is always the recommended option as it allows you to use the object / class as many times as you want while calling the full class path and name every time you want to use causes a lot of confusion and may be difficult to track in case of errors

Answer (score 10):

In the UserSeeder Class add:

**use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;**

Comment: When using this suggestion the autocomplete also worked for me in Visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed same error in Laravel 9 by importing

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
```